# Soldering crystals through wires

Tags: oscillator, crystal

Is it ok to connect a crystal (mine is 433.42MHz) to a breadboard and then to solder jumper wires from a PCB to the crystal on the breadboard? I have a strange problem in my project and I suspicious that maybe this is the problem.

EDIT:
I solved the problem. I listened to the great people here and soldered it directly to the PCB

Comment: What is the strange problem exactly?

Comment: It has to as close to the MCU with quality capacitors, no long wires.

Comment: A 433 MHz "crystal" isn't really a crystal, it's a **resonator**. How you use it in a circuit is similar to how a crystal would be used though. And as said in the answers, 433 MHz on a breadboard **is not going to work**. Period, forget about it. Also jumper wires introduce **way too much inductance**. 433 MHz will only work if you make everything **as small as possible** on a PCB or prototype board.

Comment: The typical use of such a 433 MHz **resonator** is a (usually one transistor) **transmitter / oscillator** or maybe as a **filter**. If you want to use it in any other way then expect issues, I mean, it might simply **not work**. For example if you use it with an IC that is normally used with a **crystal** (of 20 MHz for example) then that's **not going to work** with this 433 MHz resonator. TLDR: 433 MHz is **RF** and when it is **RF** then you need to **know** what you're doing, if not: it will not work and you will be dissappointed.

Comment: Thanks you all about the help, I solved the problem

Comment: Well, that's good, but how ? This could help others too

Comment: @Eitan Please tell us how you solved the problem.

Comment: I listened to the great people here and soldered it directly to the PCB

Answer (score 2):

433MHz and breadboards don't mix.

Breadboards have inductance in the pin rows, and capacitance between the pin rows.  These will completely mess up any circuit that operates at radio frequencies.

The inductance and capacitance are a side effect of the way breadboards are built.  There's not a bunch of coils or capacitors inside that you could remove.

At exactly what frequency breadboards become unusable depends on the breadboard and the circuit used.

Regardless, 433MHz is far outside of breadboard territory.  Your crystal or whatever it is will not operate on a breadboard, and the 433 MHz signal will not travel well (or at all) down plain jumper wires.

What you are trying to will not work.

---

433 MHz is unusual.  You'd normally have a lower frequency crystal and use a frequency multiplier of some kind to get the 433MHz.

Are you sure you aren't using an oscillator module, or a radio transmitter or receiver module?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing that as that even if you have good soldered connections you may be introducing stray capacitance that will pull your crystal off frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Most manufacturers warn to avoid heating the case of the crystal, as it can degrade performance and perhaps cause total malfunction. They recommend short soldering times for the leads as well.

Could you clarify if you are soldering to the case or the leads of the crystal? If you are soldering to the leads, I don't see a problem as long as you perform reasonably well. I would definitely suspecting soldering the case to cause problems however.

This is from the datasheet of a cheap chinese crystal.
[image: Image showing manufacturer recommendations]

Comment: I didn't touch the crystal with the soldering iron. I connected the crystal to a breadboard, and the wires I soldered to the pcb

Comment: I guess we need some more details. What is the configuration for the loading capacitors? The potentially long wires might make this setup unfeasible at your frequencies. (actually it probably won't work with breadboards and long wires at all, 433.42MHz is kinda high compared to most crystals)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the frequency may be marked as 433 MHz, it could be much lower since the quartz crystal could be used in a overtone oscillator along with many stages of multiplication to arrive at 433 MHz.

However it would not be good practice to attach long leads since stray inductance / capacitance could hamper the oscillation of the crystal and also cause a change in its resonant frequency.